# PHPWord DOMDocument::loadXML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 1 and p in Entity, line: 1

Tags: php, phpword, phpoffice

What is the problem in my HTML why is it not accepted?
Here is my HTML, I am using PHPWord to convert html to doc but I am getting the error below.

```
PHPWord DOMDocument::loadXML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 1 and p in Entity, line: 1

<div id="reportcontrol" class="company_products_and_operations_report">
    <div class="predetail-header">
        <div class="print-option">
            <span class="action-print" title="Print (âP)" data-type="print">
                <i class="print-report"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        <h2 class="report-title" style="border: none; float: none; margin-top: 5px;">Products & Operations</h2>
        <p></p>
        <table style="width: 222px; height: 538px;" class="report-table default-grid">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" class="TableHead"> 2015 Stores</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0">State</th>
                    <th class="ProfileHead">No of Stores </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> California</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">62</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Texas</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">34</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Florida</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">20</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Ohio</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Arizona</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">6</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Colorado</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Nevada</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Virginia</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Washington</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Maryland</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Oklahoma</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Oregon</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Arkansas</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Indiana</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Kentucky</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Louisiana</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> New Mexico</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Alabama</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Kansas</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> New York</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Pennsylvania</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileIndent0"> Tennessee</th>
                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ProfileTotal">Total</th>
                    <td class="ProfileDataTotal" style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">172</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <h3>Restaurant Brands</h3>
        <ul class="prodoplist">
            <li>BJ's Restaurant & Brewery</li>
            <li>BJ's Restaurant & Brewhouse</li>
            <li>BJ's Pizza & Grill</li>
            <li>BJ's Grill</li>
        </ul>
        <p>
            <strong>Selected Menu Items</strong>
            <br>Shareable Appetizers
                <br>BJ's Snacks & Small Bites
                    <br>Lunch Specials
                        <br>Sandwiches and Tacos
                            <br>Handcrafted Burgers
                                <br>Housemade Soups & Salads
                                    <br>Starter Salads
                                        <br>Garden Fresh Specialty Salads
                                            <br>Beverages
                                                <br>Handcrafted Beers
                                                    <br>Cocktails and Wine
                                                        <br>Pizza
                                                            <br>Pasta favorites
                                                            </p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
```

How is this not valid HTML when converting to Doc?

Here is  the phpword document

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
        $phpWord->setDefaultFontSize(10);
        $phpWord->setDefaultFontName('Calibri');
        $phpWord->setDefaultParagraphStyle(
            array(
            'spaceAfter' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::pointToTwip(0))
        );
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html, false, false);
```

Could someone help me determine what causes the error,

Disregard this text below:
What is Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book it has?

Answer (score 0):

Please check $html variable. There are apostrophe in the html. If you are using complete html as string.